# Proof: $C^\infty[0,1]$ is dense in $L^1[0,1]$

Tags: solution-verification, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

*Intro:* I would like to know if my demonstration of $C^\infty[0;1]$ is dense in $L^1[0,1]$ is correct because I didn't find any complete demonstration of that statement.

-(i) As we know from [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Measurable_Function_is_Pointwise_Limit_of_Simple_Functions) all functions in $f(x) \in L^{1}[0;1]$ are the point wise limit of a finite and countable linear combination of indicator functions.

-(ii) So from (i) we can write that there exists a function $g_\varepsilon(x)$ (wich is a finite and countable linear combinaison of indicator functions as explain in (i)) s.t it verifies pointwise convergence as follows: $\forall 0\leq x\leq 1, \; |f(x)-g_\varepsilon(x)|<\varepsilon/2 $ (such function exists according to (i) for any given $\varepsilon>0$).
Thus in this case we have: $\left \| f-g_\varepsilon \right \|_1=\int_{0}^{1}|f-g_\varepsilon|dx \leq \int_{0}^{1}|\varepsilon/2|dx = \varepsilon/2<\varepsilon$
We just prove that the set of all simple functions is dense in $L^{1}[0;1]$

-(iii) Now let define $\tilde{g}(x)=\begin{Bmatrix}
g_\varepsilon(x), x \notin \mathbb{Q}\\ 
0, x \in \mathbb{Q}
\end{Bmatrix}$. Thus: $\Rightarrow \left \|g_\varepsilon(x)-\tilde{g}(x)  \right \|_1=\int_{0\leq x \in \mathbb{Q} \leq 1}^{}|g_\varepsilon(x)|dx=0 < \varepsilon$

-(iv) Because we know that every function of type $\tilde{g}(x)$ can be approximated by a continuous function (in $L^1[0;1]$) in $C[0;1]$ so $C[0;1]$ is dense in $L^1[0;1]$.

-(v) Now by [Weierstrass Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) we know that the set of all polynomials is dense in C[0;1]. But we know too that all polynomials belong to $C^\infty[0;1]$.
So $C^\infty[0;1]$ is dense in $L^1[0,1]$.

Q.E.D

Comment: "As we know, $g_\varepsilon(x)$ only have a finite and countable number of discontinuity points" -- How so?

Comment: @BrianMoehring Thk you for your comment. Because $g_ε(x)$ is choose as in (i) that means as a finite sum (finite linear combination) of indicator functions . See here: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Measurable_Function_is_Pointwise_Limit_of_Simple_Functions the complete proof.

Comment: That doesn't relate to the number of discontinuity points at all.  For instance, the indicator of a fat cantor set in $[0,1]$ is itself an indicator function but its set of discontinuity points is the entirety of $[0,1]$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Sorry i am very new in measurable theory (in fact in this course we only use riemman integrable).  But it seems to me that from here: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Measurable_Function_is_Pointwise_Limit_of_Simple_Functions There is only $n2^n$ indicators functions in the sum. So in the maximum case we have $n2^n+1$ discontinuity "jump" points.

Comment: Right, there are only finitely many indicator functions in the sum of finitely many indicator functions.  However, even with only **one** indicator function, the set of discontinuities can be the whole space.  To proceed as you seem to want to proceed, you'd need to first approximate the indicator of a measurable set with the indicator of an open set from above, and then with the sum of the indicators of finitely many open intervals from below.

Comment: @BrianMoehring I must add that in my course we assume too that for exemple $x^{-1/4} \in L^2[0;1]$. And i don't know what is "fat cantor set in [0;1]"

Comment: @BrianMoehring 1-How can a single indicator function of the form: 1[a<x<b]0<a<b<1 can have more than two disconuities point on [0;1]????? Have you an exemple , a link to give me? 2- If we suppose that f(x) must be also Riemman integrable's. Is this make my demonstration correct? 3-I ve just erased what i ve said concerning the nbr of discontinuity point of gε(x) that must be finite. Is this make my proof correct (because still all of the discontinuity points are of type "jump" so they are limit of continuous fct)   --Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136467/discussion-between-brian-moehring-and-x0-user-0x).